# リモートサーバ（CentOS7）で設定したフォントが、ローカルPC（windows10）で見たとき文字化けする理由が知りたい

Tags: centos, 文字化け, font, msys2

- サーバー
  レンタルサーバ：かごやVPS  
  OS：CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core)  
  locale：
  　System Locale: LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8  
  　VC Keymap: n/a
  　X11 Layout: n/a
- クライアント
  OS：windows10 64bit
  ターミナル：msys
  locale：  
  　LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8  
  　LC_CTYPE="ja_JP.UTF-8"  
  　LC_NUMERIC="ja_JP.UTF-8"  
  　LC_TIME="ja_JP.UTF-8"  
  　LC_COLLATE="ja_JP.UTF-8"  
  　LC_MONETARY="ja_JP.UTF-8"  
  　LC_MESSAGES="C"  
  　LC_ALL=

CentOSにはfishをインストールして、RictyDiminishedPowerlineをフォントに設定しました。
フォント設定は以下の手順です。

```
# cd ~
# mkdir .fonts
# cd .fonts
# .fontsにRicty Diminished Powerline.ttfを作成
# fc-cache -fv
# fc-list | grep Ricty
/root/.fonts/Ricty Diminished Regular for Powerline.ttf: Ricty Diminished for Powerline:style=Regular
```

また、クライアントPCにもRictyDiminishedPowerlineをインストールして、msysのフォントに適用しました。
[image: msysのフォント設定]
しかし、画像のようにPowerlineの「⇒」のところが文字化けしています。
なぜなのでしょうか。

- 現状：msys Powerline文字化け
  [image: 現状：msys Powerline文字化け]
- 理想はこう表示させたい
  [image: 理想]

Comment: サーバ側の日本語文字コードがUTF-8になっているのは判りますが、クライアント側の文字コード設定はどうなっていますか？ 
Windowsの文字コードの標準（初期値）はShift-JISなので、そのままではUTF-8の文字が字化けします(UTF-8の文字コードを、Shift-JISだと思い込んで表示するため）。

Comment: クライアントのlocale設定を追記しました。

Comment: 文字化けの原因は、LC_MESSAGES="C"(ローカライズされたメッセージの表示には、POSIXシステム標準の英語を使うという設定)にあると思われます。
LC_MESSAGES="ja_JP.UTF-8"　という設定に変更してみてください。